# Pandas text file read and convert data frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file, text

I would like to solve the problem

```
input :
-----------
column1:Name
column2:Age

 raju  20
 kanu  24
------------
```

The above  is `input.txt` file one need to read the file and create a pandas dataframe and than need to convert to csv I am facing issue while doing it provides me with one column and consider lines as full object help would be great.

```
output :
Name Age
raju  20
kanu  24
```

Comment: Please update your question to include what things you have tried (code) and if you are having an error message when you did so. In such case, include the error message too.

Comment: A great resource for getting started with pandas: https://realpython.com/pandas-dataframe/